# How to avoid the polygon to be complex when optimizing its vertices?

Tags: graphics, polygon, computational-geometry

Suppose there's a set of 2D points to represent an initial simple polygon. Now I want to optimize the positions of each point according to some cost function. But this could make the polygon complex, i.e. the polygon intersects with itself. How can I avoid this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the polygon could be presumed to be convex, then it is simple. Simply compute the angles between each side and the next side. Each angle must be between 0 and 180 degrees for a convex polygon. The sum of those angles is well known for a closed polygon with N sides. This will result in a simple constrained optimization. (Actually, you can write those constraints in a "simpler" form than computing the angles with a trigonometric function. Cross products will suffice.)

If the polygon need not be convex, then you need to worry about edges crossing, or other degeneracies.

Comment: Thanks woodchips! The polygon is not neccessary convex. What do you mean by edge crossing? Detecting whether any segment intersects with another using sweep-line algorithm?

Comment: Exactly. This is clearly a problem for you. You need to ensure that no two edges cross, as that would obviously be a problem. You also need to watch for an edge of the polygon crossing at a vertex.

Comment: Sweep-line algorithm seems so trivial that I'm wondering if it can be formulated as an explicit constraint for optimization. Thanks.

Comment: If it is really so trivial to write, then why have you not done so already? Many things are easy to visualize, but a bit more complex when you try to write them down in actual working code.

Comment: Sorry maybe i'm using a wrong word (because of my poor English). I mean the sweep-line algorithm is not easy to be intergrated into the optimization.